# How can I convert double to currency format in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to show my numbers with `doublet type data` in money format and separate digits like the example below:

1000.578 -----> 1,000.58

10000.433 -----> 10,000.43

100000.4647474 -----> 100,000.46

I already created using kotlin extension like below:

```
fun Double.addAutomaticThousandSeparator() : String {
    val formattedNumber = String.format(Locale.US,"%,02d", this).replace(',', '.')
    return "$formattedNumber"
}
```

But it's not working and make my app `force close` with logcat like below:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4402)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2884)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2838)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2523)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2458)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2883)
        at co.id.ajsmsig.cs.simpel.shared.extensions.ExtensionsKt.addAutomaticThousandSeparator(Extensions.kt:203)
        at co.id.ajsmsig.cs.simpel.ui.switchingandredirection.switching.from.SwitchingFromAdapter$SwitchingViewHolder.bind(SwitchingFromAdapter.kt:55)
        at co.id.ajsmsig.cs.simpel.ui.switchingandredirection.switching.from.SwitchingFromAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SwitchingFromAdapter.kt:42)
        at co.id.ajsmsig.cs.simpel.ui.switchingandredirection.switching.from.SwitchingFromAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SwitchingFromAdapter.kt:21)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1308)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:350)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1676)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
2020-05-06 12:00:19.311 17536-17536/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2718)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1572)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I think the problem it's because of the format that I created. But I already search `double to money formatted` on google but still not found. Can you help me fix my kotlin `extension` with formatted `double to money`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [**`DecimalFormat`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

> DecimalFormat is a concrete subclass of NumberFormat that formats
>   decimal numbers. It has a variety of features designed to make it
>   possible to parse and format numbers in any locale, including support
>   for Western, Arabic, and Indic digits.

```
 val currency=(100000.4647474).convert()
  println("Value$currency") //100,000.46
```

Then

```
 fun Double.convert(): String {
        val format = DecimalFormat("#,###.00")
        format.isDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown = false
        return format.format(this).toString()
    }
```

Comment: How to add your function to my extension? Like in the question

Comment: I think that's not the `extension`. The `extension` should like this `Double.addAutomaticThousandSeparator() : String` Like in the question. Fyi, `extension` in my question it's working for `Long`. Then I copy paste it then create new one for `Double. But get the error. So how to make your function like `extension`?

Comment: Becuase if like that. If use that function must call like this: `convert(1000)`. But if using `extension` We can use like this: `1000.convert()` this I need.

Comment: @RRifaFauziKomara Understand. Move ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create function to chucked (3) and joined the string with ","

```
fun Double.addAutomaticThousandSeparator()
        = toInt()
    .toString()
    .reversed()
    .chunked(3)
    .joinToString(",")
    .reversed() + if (this % 1 > 0) ".${(this % 1).toString().split(".")[1].take(2)}" else ""
```

when you want to use it you can simply just call the function like this:

```
val a = 1000.578
val b = 10000.433
val c = 100000.4647474

val formatA = a.addAutomaticThousandSeparator()
val formatB = b.addAutomaticThousandSeparator()

println(formatA)
println(formatB)
println(c.addAutomaticThousandSeparator())
```

**Output**

```
1,000.57
10,000.43
100,000.46
```